React-native vision camera realtime face mask
i would like create snapchat filter mask in react native, i use https://github.com/nonam4/react-native-vision-camera-face-detector, its work perfectly, but what adapte a image mask on the face, i supose use, translation, rotation, and other to realise this ?
Thanks
For now, I can display the mask on the face that follows the face, but as soon as I turn my head, the mask doesn't turn with the face. I'm stuck at this stage
